# To detect isomorphic graphs Is it enough to check if they have the same number of same degree vertices?

Tags: graphs

Given two lists of non directional graph edges e.g.
 [(1,3),(3,5),(5,1),(5,7)] [(4,5),(2,3),(3,4),(4,2)]
In order to check if the two graphs are isomorphic is it enough to count the vertices with the same degree between them?

```
e.g. Vertice   1: 2    1: 0
               2: 0    2: 2
               3: 2    3: 2
             4,6: 0    4: 3
               5: 3    5: 1
               7: 1    6,7: 0
```

So in our example: both graphs have 2 vertices with 2 edges 1 with 3, one with one and 3 with 0

Comment: What have you tried?  We expect you to make a significant effort before asking, and to show us in the question what you tried.  Have you tried constructing a counterexample?  If not, spend some time playing around with graphs to try to see if you can construct a counterexample.  You might also read Wikipedia's article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism and ponder the fact that if the answer to your question was yes, then we'd have a polynomial-time algorithm for graph isomorphism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. If two graphs have different degree sequences, they are definitely not isomorphic, so the algorithm "half-works". But consider a six cycle versus two three-cycles. Both graphs have six vertices, all of degree two; they are not isomorphic.  Indeed, this counterexample shows that nothing based solely on degrees can work.